# redhat wget with zero timeout ignored

Tags: timeout, wget, redhat

I'm running wget command 

*wget -O - -q -t 1 --timeout=0 'http://servername.com/url'*
which invokes nodejs script running in the background. Once nodejs script completes, it shows detail in the output. If it's running for 2-3 minutes then everything is ok, but if it's running longer than 5 minutes, wget command just quits\ends\terminates without output and the script still remains running in the background. This can only be seen in the application server logs. Basically, the required output is lost.

Why does wget close even though the timeout is set to 0? It should wait for hours (on Debian it works btw, but on Redhat I see the above behavior)? Any solution that can be suggested? Thanks.